# Need help in rewriting the query

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-connector

The original query is given below:

```sql
SELECT
     id
    ,COUNT(A_NO) AS count
FROM table1
WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
AND p_no IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY id;
```

I need to rewrite the above query by not using `p_no IS NOT NULL` condition in the WHERE clause. So I tried the below 2 queries but they are taking long time to execute

```sql
SELECT
     id
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN A_NO IS NOT NULL AND p_no IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS count
FROM table1
WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
GROUP BY id;
    
    
SELECT
     id
    ,COUNT_IF(A_NO IS NOT NULL AND p_no IS NOT NULL) AS count
FROM table1
WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
GROUP BY id;
```

Is there any other way to rewrite the SQL query?

Comment: Could you provide sample data and desired results. And why your initial query doesn't work? Why you don't want to use p_no not null in where when you obviously want to filter with that field.

Comment: I'm joining multiple tables where the remaining conditions are common in other tables except this condition 'p_no IS NOT NULL', so I didn't use the initial query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your COUNT_IF seem pretty good.

but you can use [NVL2](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/nvl2.html), which returns the second or third value depending on the first null-ness, thus when `p_no` is not null count `a_no` else count `NULL` (which doesn't count)

```
SELECT
     id
    ,CASE(NVL2(p_no , a_no, NULL)) AS count
FROM table1
WHERE date = '2022-02-02'
GROUP BY id;
```

Order of next steps:

- If `DATE` is not a `DATE/TIMESTAMP` and is a `VARCHAR/TEXT` then store it as a real date.
- Order/Cluster you table/data by DATE
- Make the warehouse bigger.